# Grid View Vertical Scroll Bar with Fix Header

Tags: asp.net, gridview, scrollbar

How to show fixed header in grid view with vertical scroll bar?

That is when i scroll down header should visible.

Answer (score 7):

put the grid inside a div or `panel with scrollbar property`.But that takes extra effort to have a proper alignment.Each cell of the header table should be `aligned with each cell` of the grid.The other work around is to `fix the header of the grid` in such a way that `scrolling down shouldnt hide the header` of  the grid.Using `stylesheet` we can achieve that.

Add the following style in your code and assign the grid view or datagrid header style `css`.

```
.fixedHeader
{
  font-weight:bold;
  position:absolute;
  background-color: #006699;

  color: #ffffff;

  height: 25px;

  top: expression(Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds(document.getElementById("panelContainer")).y-25);

}
```

`"panelContainer" is the id of the panel`. `"Sys.UI.DomElement.getBounds(document.getElementById("panelContainer")).y "` gives the exact  Y location of the panel where we need to `fix the header`.25 pixel is the usual height of the header .`That much of space we had to leave for the header` so that its not going to eat up any space of the grid content.With the Panel control, we can control the `width, height, and scrollable option`. 
For our code example, we set the `height as 300px`, `the width as 100%`, and set the Panel to scroll while showing only the `vertical scrollbars`. Put your grid inside the panel.Now we have to assign the CSS class defined above  to the GridView's HeaderStyle

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelContainer" runat="server" Height="300px" Width="100%"  ScrollBars="Vertical">
  <asp:GridView ID="gvScrollableExample" runat="server">
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="fixedHeader " />
  </asp:GridView></asp:Panel>
```

This way we can fix the header at the top of the grid and scrolling down is not going to scroll the grid with the header.